# Select Firebase database on today date and month range

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

[image]

Hello. I am working on Ionic and Firebase as backend. I want to list items based on current date and also based on date range (upto a month, 3 months etc). Additionally, I also want to generate 'Total' of `incomeAmount` on that specific date as well as total quantity of items added on the same day.

I tried using firebase query but I am unable to retrieve the data as per the specific date range

Any help shall be super awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it by using Moment. changed the date format to `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` and saved the data on firebase under that date. Further looping with forEach to get the total

Hope it helps someone else too